# How do we constrain items to the navigation bar programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

Please advise if there are any method to constraining items (e.g. UIview) to the navigation bar programmatically?
Idea is to constrain a view directly below the navigation bar so that the bar will not block the view

```
collectionview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: UINavigationBar.bottomanchor),
```

Comment: Could you please post some code explaining what you've tried so far and why it didn't work?